# Like gate gone, user_likes review

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

im building simple facebook promotion app, but have a problem with like gate gone - i would still like to catch page likes if i can.

So i was thinking to use the  user_likes permission, so when use logs in my app i check if he already likes my page and if no i try to convince him to like. Of course there would be "skip" button, so users can choose and not like my page and still get to other content...

Since i don't have any experience with review process, will such use of user_likes permission be approved from facebook or how should we do it?

Thanks for any information!

Comment: even if you present a skip button, it would not be allowed. and you will definitely not get user_likes approved for this.

Comment: Ok - for what would i get it approved?

Comment: for stuff that "improves the user experience". definitely not for this.

Comment: Yep, im just asking what "improves the user experience" might be.. I get it that fb doesn't want like gate in some other form, but really interested in what gets fb approved and what not. It's really new to me.